# Repeats samples

Tags: statistical-significance

I am testing the effects of four antibiotics on bacterial growth. I have data of three independent experiments each has three repeats could I use the data of three repeats when I do statistics or l should take the average of three repeats before I plot the data.

Comment: Hi there and welcome. Well, to start with please tell us what you want to investigate with these experiments. – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 1):

You can treat descriptive and inferential testing differently. You specific question was how to plot the data and with this little data, I would definitively plot all the (little) data. Nine points for nine observations are something, the human eye can handle.

As for inferential statistics, the answer is not necessarily that obvious but you will probably not find much from three means so you should strive to find a test that takes all you data into account. We know too little about your experiment but a Kruskall-Wallis-Test may be a possible alternative.